how to show that an enum is tied to a class?
I have a class, Transaction that has a member type that shows the transaction's type.
E.g.:
enum TransactionType { type1, type2 }

class Transaction {
  TransactionType type;
}

Transaction t;
t.type = TransactionType.type1;

But TransactionType is only meant to be used with Transaction, so I would much rather be able to have something that would not pollute the namespace. Something like this:
class Transaction {
  Transaction::Type type;

  enum Type { type1, type2 }
}

Transaction t;
t.type = Transaction::Type.type1;

I have encountered the need to nest classes or enums a few times and am not sure what is the right practice in this scenario.

Maybe make the enum library-local?  Anything that needs to reference it globally needs a unique name for the enum type and its elements.
